# Как сделать запись в нужном блоке товар добавлен после добавления в карзину

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть код HTML в нём есть `class="add"`, после добавления товара должно в этом диве появится `товар добавлен!!`

далее код jquery

```
<div id="wripper">
    <div class="name"> Товар №
        <?=$i?>
        <img src="images/img.png" alt="">
        <input type="text" size="3" id="item<?=$i?>" />
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">Добавить товар</a>
        <div class="add"></div>
    </div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('.name a').click(function(){

    var count = $(this).parent().find('input').val();

    var id = $(this).parent().find('input').attr('id');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {itemid: id, count: count},
        success: function(data){
          $(this).parent().find('.add').html('Товар добавлен!');
          //-ЧТО ТУТ НЕ ТАК-
        }

     });

   });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.name a').click(function(){

    var count = $(this).parent().find('input').val();

    var id = $(this).parent().find('input').attr('id');

    $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'post.php',
        data: {itemid: id, count: count},
        success: function(data){
          $this.parent().find('.add').html('Товар добавлен!');
        }

     });

   });

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Вместо `$(this).parent().find('.add').html('Товар добавлен!');`

```
$('#wripper .add').html('Товар добавлен!');
```